# Installing python-sympy in a Docker image

Tags: python, docker, sympy

I am trying to install Sympy in a Docker image based on Debian using a  Dockerfile:

```
FROM  debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python \
    build-essential \
    make \
    gcc \
    pandoc \
    lrslib \
    dos2unix \
    python-dev \
    python-pygments \
    python-numpy \
    python-pip 

RUN  apt-get -y install python-sympy
....
```

At the second RUN command, the APT tool informs me that it will have to download 900 MB (!) of dependencies, most of which are fonts. This makes no sense whatsoever, since Sympy is a pure Python package.

I then tried the standard setup:

```
....
COPY    sympy-0.7.6.tar.gz /sympy-0.7.6.tar.gz
RUN     tar -xzvf /sympy-0.7.6.tar.gz
WORKDIR /sympy-0.7.6
RUN     python setup.py install
```

This works, but in the running container Sympy returns string formatting errors which I do not see on my own Linux installation. Grateful for any tips.

Comment: I'd guess that the pretty printing functionality is where the fonts come in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess those 900MB are not dependencies, but recommendations.

```
$ apt-cache show python-sympy
Package: python-sympy
Priority: optional
Section: universe/python
Installed-Size: 14889
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Georges Khaznadar <georgesk@debian.org>
Architecture: all
Source: sympy
Version: 0.7.4.1-1
Depends: python (>= 2.7), python (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2)
Recommends: python-imaging, python-ctypes, ipython, python-numpy, texlive-fonts-extra, dvipng
Filename: pool/universe/s/sympy/python-sympy_0.7.4.1-1_all.deb
Size: 2826308
MD5sum: 4bfdb84df0e626f13b46b0d44517a492
SHA1: bcc0a9b24d6f974d3ece4b770fc607f25a9e61f6
SHA256: 3c490be9ab494a37ff4a5f5729f1de261546391acc5377a4b48c40cbee0657fa
Description-en: Computer Algebra System (CAS) in Python
 SymPy is a Python library for symbolic mathematics (manipulation). It aims to
 become a full-featured computer algebra system (CAS) while keeping the code as
 simple as possible in order to be comprehensible and easily extensible. SymPy
 is written entirely in Python and does not require any external libraries,
 except optionally for plotting support.
Description-md5: 6056e6cef6dcfe0106530b41d92b60d5
Homepage: https://github.com/sympy/sympy
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

You cam omit the recommendations using the `--no-install-recommends` option, so can use it in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM  debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python \
    build-essential \
    make \
    gcc \
    pandoc \
    lrslib \
    dos2unix \
    python-dev \
    python-pygments \
    python-numpy \
    python-pip 

RUN  apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install python-sympy
```

Comment: Quick and simple answer. Thank you. Sympy now runs without errors.